# Twilio sms Arabic letters appears as question marks

Tags: java, twilio, sms, twilio-api

When trying to send an SMS message in Arabic, using Twilio sdk version is 7.43.1
a question marks arrives to the logs and mobile meanwhile if I send the sms using the API the message arrives correctly.
What is the problem here

```
MessageCreator messageCreator = Message.creator(
new com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber(phone),
messageServiceId,"مرحبا");
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the apache org.apache.httpcomponents to 4.5.x was the solution since apache 4.4.x has an encoding bug